# ORDER COLUMN USING SUM() OVER()

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column  (COLUMN3) that is out of order in some cases. I need to preserve the COLUMN1 order and then show the correct order for the new column "NUM_ITEM". I don't know how to do this.
I tried:

```
SELECT CODIMP,COLUMN1,COLUMN2,COLUMN3, 
SUM(CASE WHEN COLUMN2 = ('C170') THEN 1 
ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY COLUMN2 ORDER BY TO_NUMBER(COLUMN1)) NUM_ITEM

FROM SPED_DATA 
WHERE CODIMP = 81 AND COLUMN2 IN ('C100','C170')

GROUP BY CODIMP,COLUMN1,COLUMN2,COLUMN3
ORDER BY TO_NUMBER(COLUMN1);
```

The result is like:

```
CODIMP  COLUMN1 COLUMN2 COLUMN3 NUM_ITEM    EXPECTED
81      2741    C100    0       0           0
81      2742    C170    4       1           1
81      2743    C170    2       2           2
81      2744    C170    1       3           3
81      2745    C170    3       4           4
81      2746    C100    0       0           0
81      2747    C170    2       5           1
81      2748    C170    1       6           2
81      2749    C100    0       0           0
81      2750    C170    1       7           1
81      2751    C100    0       0           0
81      2752    C170    1       8           1
```

The column "EXPECTED" is how I need to see the column "NUM_ITEM".

Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your question and add the input data used. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a difference of row numbers approach you can classify groups and then use `row_number` for successive rows.

```
select CODIMP,COLUMN1,COLUMN2,COLUMN3
,case when column2=170 then row_number() over(partition by codimp,column2,grp order by to_number(column1)) 
else 0 end as num_item
from (
SELECT CODIMP,COLUMN1,COLUMN2,COLUMN3, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CODIMP ORDER BY TO_NUMBER(COLUMN1))
-ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CODIMP,COLUMN2 ORDER BY TO_NUMBER(COLUMN1)) NUM_ITEM as grp
FROM SPED_DATA 
WHERE CODIMP = 81 AND COLUMN2 IN ('C100','C170')
) t
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to separate the values into groups, where column 2 is 100.  You can do this with a cumulative sum.  Then, after that, use `row_number()`:

```
select sd.*,
       row_number() over (partition by grp order by column1) as expected
from (select sd.*,
             sum(case when column2 = 'C100' then 1 else 0 end) over (order by column1) as grp
      from sped_data sd
      where column2 in ('C100', 'C170') and codimp = 81
     ) sd;
```

I'm not sure if you actually need to order the results.  It seems that `order by column1` is sufficient for the result set.